# Ionic app android publish

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I deploy app ionic using command ionic build cordova android but when I open

android studio and run app it show me ionic blank page rather than login page.

Why?

[image: App]

Comment: are you sure you are opening the right project? also you dont need to open android studio to run app in emulator

Comment: I assume that you have created this app using "blank" template. Please show us your app logic which redirects app to login page if no credentials were detected.